# C# Create a Truncated Collection with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I don't know if this is possible, but lets say I have a `List` with an object that has X number of properties. I then want to filter the list but I want to only get back very specific properties back from the list. I'm looking to do this with LINQ

I know that I can use a `SELECT` but that still keeps the properties I dont want, only with blank values. But I don't want these properties to appear in the resulting List. Can this be done?

Comment: Return an anonymous class, cotaining only desired properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you select instances of a particular type, and don't populate all of its values, then you will indeed receive instances with non-populated values.  It sounds like you want to select an entirely new type.

You can create a custom type:

```
public class SomeType
{
    public string SomeValue { get; set; }
}
```

And select instances of that type:

```
.Select(x => new SomeType { SomeValue = x.SomeValue })
```

Or, if you don't want to define the class, you can select it inline as an anonymous type:

```
.Select(x => new { SomeValue = x.SomeValue });
```

The two will generally behave the same in consuming code.

Comment: Thank you! The last item is what I was really looking for, the anonymous type. That worked great and got me what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with Select method easily:

```
var filteredList = list.Select(element => 
                                   new MyClass  {
                                                 // set necessary properties like
                                                  Name = element.Name,
                                                  ...
                                                 }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Like so:

```
class Foo
{
    public int PropertyOne { get; set; }
    public string PropertyTwo { get; set; }
}

var theList = new List<Foo> {
    // some foo go here 
};

var filtered = theList.Select(f=> new {PropertyOne = f.PropertyOne }).ToList();
```